# aws elastic beanstalk cannot create scaling trigger fails with AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh null values not allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, cloudwatch-alarms

When I try to specify a scaling trigger it keeps erroring with

```
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:[/Resources/AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh/Type/Dimensions/0/Value/Fn::GetAtt/0] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

I have a saved template and I am trying to add

```
aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    BreachDuration: 5
    LowerBreachScaleIncrement: -1
    LowerThreshold: 0.75
    MeasureName: Latency
    Period: 1
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Statistic: Average
    Unit: Seconds
    UpperBreachScaleIncrement: 2
    UpperThreshold: 1
```

So I created it without this in which it created the auto alarm. I tried to update to this setting using the browser but it also failed with message

```
Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:[/Resources/AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh/Type/Dimensions/0/Value/Fn::GetAtt/0] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

Here is my saved template

```
Platform:
  PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.14
OptionSettings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    BatchSize: '30'
    BatchSizeType: Percentage
  AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy.aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    UpperBreachScaleIncrement: '2'
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: domain.settings
    PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH
    ALLOWED_CIDR_NETS: 10.0.0.0/16
    DATABASE_NAME: domainproductionplus
    DATABASE_HOST: domain-production-plus.coz8h02qupfe.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
    ENVIRONMENT: production
    DATABASE_PORT: '5432'
    EMAIL_BACKEND: django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend
    DEBUG: '0'
    DATABASE_ENGINE: django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2
    REDIS_LOCATION: aws-co-qemfpydhs2ly.ubjsxm.0001.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME: eu-west-2
    ALLOWED_HOSTS: '*'
    VAPID_ADMIN_EMAIL: email@domain.com
    DATABASE_USER: domainprodplus
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME: domain-production-plus
    REDIS_LOCATION_X: domain-production-plus-001.domain-production-plus.ubjsxm.euw2.cache.amazonaws.com
    DATABASE_PASSWORD: '{{resolve:ssm:domain-api-production-plus-DATABASE_PASSWORD:1}}'
    HASHID_SALT: '{{resolve:ssm:domain-api-production-plus-HASHID_SALT:1}}'
    VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY: '{{resolve:ssm:domain-api-production-plus-VAPID_PRIVATE_KEY:1}}'
    VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY: '{{resolve:ssm:domain-api-production-plus-VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY:1}}'
    SECRET_KEY: '{{resolve:ssm:domain-api-production-plus-SECRET_KEY:1}}'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: '{{resolve:ssm:domain-api-production-plus-AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:1}}'
  aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate:
    RollingUpdateType: Health
    RollingUpdateEnabled: true
  aws:elb:policies:
    domainionDrainingEnabled: true
  aws:ec2:instances:
    InstanceTypes: t2.micro
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup.aws:autoscaling:asg:
    Cooldown: '120'
    MaxSize: '6'
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: domain/wsgi.py
    StaticFiles: /static/=www/static/
  aws:ec2:vpc:
    VPCId: vpc-0fddefb70e6c8b32a
    Subnets: subnet-04497865d7eb17b70
    AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default:
    DeregistrationDelay: 20
    HealthCheckInterval: 15
    HealthCheckPath: /app-version-updates
    HealthCheckTimeout: 5
    HealthyThresholdCount: 3
    MatcherHTTPCode: 200
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
    StickinessEnabled: false
    StickinessLBCookieDuration: 86400
    StickinessType: lb_cookie
    UnhealthyThresholdCount: 5
  aws:elbv2:listener:80:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    Protocol: HTTP
    Rules: domainapiproductionplus
  aws:elbv2:listener:443:
    ListenerEnabled: true
    SSLCertificateArns: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-2:799479065523:certificate/5fb4f19c-f377-4ef6-8a7a-9657832c0d17
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Rules: domainapiproductionplus
    SSLPolicy: ELBSecurityPolicy-TLS-1-2-2017-01
  aws:elbv2:listenerrule:domainapiproductionplus:
    HostHeaders: api-production-plus.hcidomain.digital
    PathPatterns: /*
    Priority: 2
    process: default
  aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    CrossZone: true
    ManagedSecurityGroup: sg-0ac0850967d4d2929
  aws:elbv2:loadbalancer:
    ManagedSecurityGroup: sg-0ac0850967d4d2929
    SharedLoadBalancer: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:799479065523:loadbalancer/app/domain-production-plus/206b8390c82843a3
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:
    ServiceRole: arn:aws:iam::799479065523:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
    LoadBalancerType: application
    LoadBalancerIsShared: true
  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    IamInstanceProfile: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
    EC2KeyName: domain
    SecurityGroups: sg-0ac0850967d4d2929,sg-095397beca170840e,sg-02f17712a24784d64
    MonitoringInterval: 1 minute
  aws:autoscaling:trigger:
    BreachDuration: 5
    LowerBreachScaleIncrement: -1
    LowerThreshold: 0.75
    MeasureName: Latency
    Period: 1
    EvaluationPeriods: 1
    Statistic: Average
    Unit: Seconds
    UpperBreachScaleIncrement: 2
    UpperThreshold: 1
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system:
    SystemType: enhanced
EnvironmentTier:
  Type: Standard
  Name: WebServer
AWSConfigurationTemplateVersion: 1.1.0.0
Tags:
  project: domain
  product: domain
```

I am using a shared load balancer, could this be the issue? with classic load balancer it works fine - setting the autoscale metric to use Latency.

To create the environment from cli I run.

```
% eb create domain-api-production-plus --cfg domain-api-production-plus \
--cname domain-api-production-plus \
--elb-type application \
--shared-lb arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:799479065523:loadbalancer/app/domain-production-plus/206b8390c82843a3 \
--vpc \
--vpc.ec2subnets subnet-04497865d7eb17b70,subnet-032624d3e62d499f1 \
--vpc.elbsubnets subnet-0b3c3aa9b190a2546,subnet-05453d986413e8ae2 \
--vpc.id vpc-0fddefb70e6c8b32a \
--vpc.securitygroups sg-02f17712a24784d64,sg-095397beca170840e,sg-0ac0850967d4d2929 \
--tags project=domain,Name=domain-api-production-plus \
--service-role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role \
--region eu-west-2 \
--platform "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.14" \
--keyname domain


Do you want to associate a public IP address? (Y/n): n
Do you want the load balancer to be public? (Select no for internal) (Y/n):
Creating application version archive "app-5aac-200929_084247".
Uploading Domain/app-5aac-200929_084247.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: domain-api-production-plus
  Application name: Domain
  Region: eu-west-2
  Deployed Version: app-5aac-200929_084247
  Environment ID: e-tcwd2awzvs
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:eu-west-2::platform/Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.14
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: domain-api-production-plus.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2020-09-29 07:42:50.765000+00:00
Printing Status:
2020-09-29 07:42:49    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2020-09-29 07:42:50    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-2-799479065523 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2020-09-29 07:42:55    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-AWSEBManagedLBSecurityGroup-dw7edzemvt.
2020-09-29 07:43:13    INFO    Created target group named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:799479065523:targetgroup/awseb-domain--default-38qig/440561c9ab287e68
2020-09-29 07:43:13    INFO    Created security group named: sg-0e16398cbceab94d6
2020-09-29 07:43:14    INFO    Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-1I6T492EE9NN1
2020-09-29 07:43:30    INFO    Created Load Balancer listener rule named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:799479065523:listener-rule/app/domain-production-plus/206b8390c82843a3/57e3715de5b24a02/0f045a9230df4191
2020-09-29 07:43:30    INFO    Created Load Balancer listener rule named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:799479065523:listener-rule/app/domain-production-plus/206b8390c82843a3/57e3715de5b24a02/f42374f1622dbd49
2020-09-29 07:43:30    INFO    Created Load Balancer listener rule named: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-2:799479065523:listener-rule/app/domain-production-plus/206b8390c82843a3/457d5212b3cacc19/aa1f1cd2117f1290
2020-09-29 07:44:17    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1I5GB63XJKP1Y
2020-09-29 07:44:17    INFO    Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
2020-09-29 07:44:17    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-2:799479065523:scalingPolicy:664aebe1-ba1f-4d20-aed5-b44204b3a702:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1I5GB63XJKP1Y:policyName/awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-ZTC3D3FZQPZT
2020-09-29 07:44:17    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-west-2:799479065523:scalingPolicy:c2431b1c-1efa-4927-a7ad-cdba75fa47ae:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1I5GB63XJKP1Y:policyName/awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-2MVWR52GOSTF
2020-09-29 07:44:32    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-1OBABSCE98Y89
2020-09-29 07:44:32    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-tcwd2awzvs-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-UOJ9YBPCAIOH
2020-09-29 07:45:36    INFO    Successfully launched environment: domain-api-production-plus
```

**UPDATE**

So I cannot find the TargetResponseTime on the beanstalk environment.

[image: beantstalk metric]

Comment: The template posted does not have `aws:autoscaling:trigger`. Maybe there is some indentation issue in the template you are actually trying to deploy?

Comment: updated with it included

Comment: In the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-autoscaling-triggers.html#environments-cfg-autoscaling-triggers-namespace) they have a bit different format for the triggers. Not sure if yours is equivalent or not?

Comment: I have been using this guide. which one do I follow? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html

Comment: If possible, you could try with the second format. I don't know why there are two. Maybe they are equivalent.

Comment: same error, even if I remove this and create the environment its fine but if I EB config in the browser and try to change it it errors the same too.

Answer (score 1):

> I am using a shared load balancer, could this be the issue? with classic load balancer it works fine - setting the autoscale metric to use Latency..

`Latency` metric is [only for](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-cloudwatch-metrics.html) CLB, not other load balancer types:

> Latency: [HTTP listener] The total time elapsed, in seconds, from the time the load balancer sent the request to a registered instance until the instance started to send the response headers.

For the ALB, the closest metric [would be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-cloudwatch-metrics.html#load-balancer-metrics-alb):

> TargetResponseTime: The time elapsed, in seconds, after the request leaves the load balancer until a response from the target is received. This is equivalent to the target_processing_time field in the access logs.

In your config file there is mixture of ALB and CLB settings. For example, `aws:elb:loadbalancer` is for CLB, while `aws:elbv2:loadbalancer` with `SharedLoadBalancer` is only for ALB.

Your [aws:autoscaling:trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-autoscalingtrigger) is using `Latency`, which as explained above, is only for CLB. For ALB, it should be `TargetResponseTime`.

I can't verify if changing `MeasureName` in your ASG will solve all the issues you are having, but this is definitely a part which contributes to the problems.

Comment: @shorif2000 If you don't have `TargetResponseTime` then it means you are using CLB, not ALB. But in your config files you are using `SharedLoadBalancer` which is only for ALB. So Its getting confusing what is your setup actually.  I think this is in part a reason why there are some issues with it.

Comment: I am trying to use a shared ALB

Comment: @shorif2000 Are you trying to modify existing EB env and change from CLB to ALB? Or you are creating new one from scratch? If the latter, why do you have CLB relevant settings in your config files?

Comment: I was trying to move CLB to a ALB